# Handling related NSMutable arrays in a series of operations

Tags: ios, matrix, nsmutablearray

This may be out of the scope of what Objective C can do.

It involves doing something to a named variable (e.g. 15 different operations), and then doing those 15 operations on a similarly named variable, and so on for let's say 10 variables.

Suppose I have a set of 10 NSMutableArray;e.g.

```
NSMutableArray *a =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
... 
NSMutableArray *j =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and I do 15 operation on them to get 15 different variables (also arrays or more accurately NSMutableArray's).  Let's say the first thing I do is to make a computation the is the product of a thru j:

```
for (int i=0;i<[a count]; i++)
    aProduct = /* some operation upon NSMutableArray a*/...;
...
for (int i=0;i<[j count]; i++)
    jProduct = /* some operation upon NSMutableArray j*/...;
```

Let's say the 15th thing I do is to make a computation the is the selection of a thru j:

```
for (int i=0;i<[a count]; i++)
    aSelection = /* some operation upon NSMutableArray a*/...;
...
for (int i=0;i<[j count]; i++)
    jSelection = /* some operation upon NSMutableArray j*/...;
```

Right now I'm using switch / case for the coding, which involves a lot of thinking, initialization, and even caught that I made a typo in one "case" statement (leaving out a break) and when I copied the code, that mistake propagated down.

So is there a way to avoid having 15 sets of "switch / case" code, and doing it instead "dynamically" (if such a thing exists in Xcode and iOS) and avoiding creating 10 times 15 variables?

Or that I create and declare the 150 variables, but do so in some array, perhaps by using the addressing (&a  thru &j) of the variable?

This is getting very complex, very quickly, and there are times when some of the 10 arrays have many elements, and other of the same arrays are null (e.g. a may have 20 elements, and j has null elements)

PS: (Postscript at 6:56pm NYC time 19Mar2012)  I was actually hoping that I could use some variable name and then prefix or suffix it with the letters a thru j; eg:

ProductA = [[....;
SelectorA=....;

and have the subroutine just take a letter from A to J via enum to translate that to 0 to 9.

I'm not rejecting the solution proposed earlier by Peter Cetinski; I just haven't tried to implement it yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain the computed values for each array, then try using array of arrays

```
NSMutableArray *arrOfArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrOfArrays addObject:a];
.....
[arrOfArrays addObject:j];

for ( NSMutableArray *arr in arrOfArrays ) {
   for (int i=0;i<[arr count]; i++) {
      aProduct = /* some operation upon NSMutableArray arr*/...;
      .....
      aSelection = /* some operation upon NSMutableArray arr*/...;

      //do something with your computed values
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer.  <br/>  First, I have to declare 10 times 15 arrays, right?  <br/>Second, within the inner of the 2 "for loops", I see you have aProduct and aSelection, where that would not work for b, c, ..., j.  <br/>  In other words, I want just "Product" and when it is working with "a" or "j", it would prefix the word "Product" and "Selection" with "a" thru "j"<br/>  Unless, of course, you have a typo by putting aProduct instead of Product, etc.

Comment: No, you only need one array that contains 10 arrays.  Yes, I was just using your pseudocode for aProduct.  Product would be set for each of your "letter" data sets.